# How can I change IntProperty default value?

Tags: python, scripting

I've got 2 properties. My first:

```
hT = EnumProperty(items=(('A', "None", ""),
                         ('B',"LeMans 40", ""),
                         ('C',"LeMans 45", ""),
                         ('D',"LeMans 50", ""),
                         ('E',"LeMans 60", "")), 
                         default='C', name="Hardeware type")
```

My second:

```
 fW = IntProperty(name="Width", 
             default=838, min=800, max=2700, description="Furniture width")
```

My first property is for choosing the hardware of my furniture.
Each hardware needs a minimum dimension of its furniture. So, for example, if I choose "LeMans 60", the "default" and "min" value of my second property need to change to 998.

Is it possible to do that or do I need to create a property with its own default, min and max value ?

Comment: I don't think you can do that, but a work around is to use update function for the first prop to set the value of the second and have the largest range (from min to max ) set for the second vale, and use an other update function for the second to check the state of the first and do the clipping job(to overcome  a fixed max min )

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/195459/how-can-i-change-intproperty-default-value-stored-within-propertygroup

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that to an actual instance:

```
import bpy
bpy.types.Object.prop = bpy.props.IntProperty()

bpy.context.active_object.prop
# this evaluates what the value is and returns <class 'int'> - not subscriptable
```

[image]

To adjust the min max etc. you need to re-declare it:

```
bpy.types.Object.prop = bpy.props.IntProperty(min=100, max=300)
# note: re-declaring will change it for all the objects
```

Changing the `default` value will not change the actual value of that static property - you will need to assign it a new value in that case. But newly created objects will have this new default.

You can make it work like this:

1. create [callback function](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_66_release/bpy.props.html#update-example) for your `hT` property
2. have this function re-declare your `fW` property with new parameters based on `hT` value

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Finally, i think i'll create property for each furniture, more simple for me. Hope i don't need tout create too much hardeware ^^

Comment: Has Blender changed to where we have to use `bpy.props.IntProperty` instead of using `bpy.types...`?  I can only get it to work using `props`.  And accessing the `dict` via `['soft_max']` doesn't work for me either, I can only update the property by re-declaring it.

Comment: @jdk1.0 you are right, it no longer works.