# How to redefine an Float Property after create it?

Tags: python, scripting, interface

I've created a slider like so:

```
bpy.types.Scene.slider_value = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
    default= 0,
    min = -100,
    max =  100, 
    )
```

In some case I need to go out over the previous  min and max values.
It is possible to simply redefine the Float Property ?

Comment: I got a good result from creating an operator containing the same code with the new value. Is the a way to properly do this ?

Comment: another duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28086/how-can-i-change-intproperty-default-value/28091#28091

Comment: I was frustrated to not get more possibilities. I'm pretty sure this will work fine tank you @Jerryno