# Adding a Property to a CollectionProperty After Creating it

Tags: python, scripting, properties

O, I have this Collection Property:

```
class particle_instancer(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    particle_object = StringProperty (name = "Object", description = "")
    particle_material = StringProperty (name = "Material", description = "")

bpy.utils.register_class(particle_instancer)
bpy.types.Scene.particle_instancer = CollectionProperty(type = particle_instancer)
```

And then I have an operator that is supposed to add a **StringProperty()** to its first item.

If Instead of a CollectionProperty I used the scene as the "Container" for the properties, I could simply do:

```
bpy.types.Scene.my_prop = StringProperty()
```

I thought I could do:

```
bpy.types.particle_instancer.my_prop = StringProperty()
```

But this leads to nothing as the property doesn't get register and it doesn't give me any error StackTrace neither. So is it possible to do? If yes how could I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add properties to the `PropertyGroup` as follows:

```
bpy.types.Scene.particle_instancer[1]['type'].my_prop = bpy.props.StringProperty()
```

---

Internally, your `bpy.types.Scene.particle_instancer` is a `tuple` that will look like this:

```
(<built-in function CollectionProperty>, {'type': <class '__main__.particle_instancer'>, 'attr': 'particle_instancer'})
```

So, you can index the `dict` giving you access to the `particle_instancer` `class`, where you can add properties.

I got the idea to access the `'type'` from this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28091/20051

Answer (score 2):

You can only assign values or add new class attributes per item.

```
import bpy

class CustomGroup(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    id = bpy.props.IntProperty()
    foo = bpy.props.StringProperty()
    ...

bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
bpy.types.Scene.custom_group = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=CustomGroup)

>>> item = bpy.context.scene.custom_group.add()
>>> item.id = 0
>>> item.name = "Cube"
>>> item.foo = "Sphere"
>>> item.foo
>>> 'Sphere'
```

Comment: I was able to add new class attributes with `bpy.types.Scene.custom_group[1]['type'].my_new_prop = ...`