# How can I change IntProperty default value stored within PropertyGroup?

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to dynamically modify IntProperty default value. Currently, it is stored in `bpy.types.Scene.mysettings` as PropertyGroup. So far I've succeeded in updating the default value only by assigning a duplicated class that has been updated with new default value and pre-registered using `bpy.utils`.

Is there any easier way to do this? Is there a way to redeclare single property without reassigning whole class or is the solution really dynamically creating and assigning Classes?

*Working example:*

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import PointerProperty
from bpy.types import PropertyGroup, Panel

def update_default_value(self, context):
    settings = context.scene.mysettings
    # Current solution: assigning different PropertyGroup Class to update default val
    bpy.types.Scene.mysettings = PointerProperty(type=UpdatedSettings)

class AAA_PT_Demo(Panel):
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_context = "objectmode"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_label = "My Demo"
    bl_category = "Demo"

    def draw(self, context):
        settings = context.scene.mysettings
        layout = self.layout
        layout.prop(settings, 'myboolean')
        layout.prop(settings, 'myint')


class MySettings(PropertyGroup):
    myboolean : bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name = "On Check Update Default",
        default = True,
        update = update_default_value
        )

    myint : bpy.props.IntProperty(
        name = "My Int",
        step = 5,
        default = 10,
        )

class UpdatedSettings(PropertyGroup):
    myboolean : bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name = "On Check Update Default",
        default = True,
        update = update_default_value
        )

    myint : bpy.props.IntProperty(
        name = "My Int",
        step = 5,
        default = 999, # New Default Value
        )
        
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MySettings)
    bpy.utils.register_class(UpdatedSettings)
    bpy.utils.register_class(AAA_PT_Demo)
    bpy.types.Scene.mysettings = PointerProperty(type=MySettings)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MySettings)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(UpdatedSettings)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(AAA_PT_Demo)
    del bpy.types.Scene.mysettings

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Useful resources I found on the way:

1. [How to create PropertyGroup](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#propertygroup-example) (original doc):
2. [How to create and access PropertyGroup](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/creating-and-accessing-propertygroup-instances/14332/9) (discussion)
3. [Changing default value of IntProperty](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28086/how-can-i-change-intproperty-default-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up dynamically creating + registering a class and then reassigning it back to the same `mysettings` property. It works in this POC, but I have to try it in the real addon. Feel free to suggest any other solutions or make edits to this one.

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import PointerProperty
from bpy.types import PropertyGroup, Panel

myproperties = [
    {
        "type": "bool",
        "name": "mybool",
        "attributes": {
            "name": "On Check Update Default"
        }
    },
    { 
        "type": "int",
        "name": "myint",
        "attributes": {
            "name": "My Int",
            "default": 999
        }
    }
]


def update_default_value(self, context):
    dattributes = {}    
    for property in myproperties:
        propType = property["type"]
        propName = property["name"]
        if propType == "bool":
            dattributes[propName] = (bpy.props.BoolProperty, property["attributes"])
        elif propType == "int":
            dattributes[propName] = (bpy.props.IntProperty, property["attributes"])

    DynamicClass = type('DynamicClassName', (PropertyGroup,), {'__annotations__': dattributes})
    bpy.utils.register_class(DynamicClass)
    bpy.types.Scene.mysettings = PointerProperty(type=DynamicClass)
        


class AAA_PT_Demo(Panel):
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_context = "objectmode"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_label = "My Demo"
    bl_category = "Demo"

    def draw(self, context):
        settings = context.scene.mysettings
        layout = self.layout
        layout.prop(settings, 'mybool')
        layout.prop(settings, 'myint')


class MySettings(PropertyGroup):
    mybool : bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name = "On Check Update Default",
        default = True,
        update = update_default_value
        )

    myint : bpy.props.IntProperty(
        name = "My Int",
        step = 5,
        default = 10,
        )
        
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MySettings)
    bpy.utils.register_class(AAA_PT_Demo)
    bpy.types.Scene.mysettings = PointerProperty(type=MySettings)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MySettings)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(AAA_PT_Demo)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(DinamicClass) # yet not sure how to unregister dynamic class
    del bpy.types.Scene.mysettings

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Again, along the way I found some really useful articles:

- [Blender 2.8 field property declaration and dynamic class creation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118118/blender-2-8-field-property-declaration-and-dynamic-class-creation) (Stack Overflow)
- [Dynamic Blender property creation](https://blog.hamaluik.ca/posts/dynamic-blender-properties/) by Kenton Hamaluik

Answer (score 2):

**Use a setter getter**

Instead of setting the default of the property, emulate a property with a getter setter that retrieves the custom property when set, else some default we have set.

[Internal "get/set" function of property?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126458/internal-get-set-function-of-property)

As an example have added another intproperty in same prop group as a means to adjust the default value without any re-registering trickery.. *which can turn ugly and strip the RNA if it gets out of sync*.

[image]
*Demo gif, changing setting of default is matched by `myint` till set*

While `myint` has not been set it is given the default value. Once it is set it uses the value set.

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import PointerProperty
from bpy.types import PropertyGroup, Panel

class AAA_PT_Demo(Panel):
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_context = "objectmode"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_label = "My Demo"
    bl_category = "Demo"

    def draw(self, context):
        settings = context.scene.mysettings
        layout = self.layout
        layout.prop(settings, 'default')
        layout.prop(settings, 'myint')


class MySettings(PropertyGroup):
    def get_myint(self):
        return self.get("myint", self.default)
    
    def set_myint(self, value):
        self["myint"] = value
        
        
    default : bpy.props.IntProperty(
        name = "My Int Default",
        step = 5,
        default = 44
        )    
    myint : bpy.props.IntProperty(
        name = "My Int",
        step = 5,
        get=get_myint,
        set=set_myint,
        )

classes = (MySettings,
           AAA_PT_Demo,
           )
           
def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.Scene.mysettings = PointerProperty(type=MySettings)

def unregister():
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    del bpy.types.Scene.mysettings

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Other possiblilties are storing the default properties on another "toolsettings" prop group, or instead of using an annotated property def, simply declare a class variable `default = 44` in the prop group and grab it from the class.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't solve exact issue I am tackling. I need the default to be explicitly set to the property so it can be reset using **hover on property + backspace** or my operator that resets values to default.

Comment: Also, I cannot see how moving default properties to another prop group would work for the same reason mentioned above. To give a better Idea of **exact usecase**: user selects preset (an update fn is being triggered) and new preset values are to be set as new default values.